# Returning success indicator when executing a Deferred in twisted

Tags: python, asynchronous, twisted, deferred

I am using Twisted, and I would like the single deferred operation to return an indicator if it succeeded or not just like when using the DeferredList.

This works with multiple deferrds:

```
my_query = deferToThread(self.mongo_pool.db[self.collection_name].find_one,
        {
            some_query
        }
    )

(my_success_1, my_data_1), (my_success_2, my_data_2) = 
         await DeferredList([ensureDeferred(my_query_1), ensureDeferred(my_query_2)])
```

But doing that with just one deferred returns the data directly:

```
my_return = await ensureDeferred(my_query)
```

When I wrap it under a Deferred, the application just hangs and doesn't respond:

```
my_return = await Deferred(ensureDeferred(my_query))
```

So, what I end up doing to get that indicator is the following and it works, but it definitely looks wrong:

```
my_return = await DeferredList([ensureDeferred(my_query)])
(my_success_indicator, my_data) = my_return[0]
```

Is there a better way of doing it? I am on Twisted version 17.05

Comment: Are you using MongoDB's official library or `txmongo`?

Comment: @notorious.no no, using pymongo

Comment: `deferToThread` encapsulates into a `Deferred` for you. There's no reason to use `ensureDeferred`. Simply yield or await for `my_query`.

Comment: yes, but then I don't get the success indicator, just the data

Comment: well, I get the success indicator from DeferredList, so yeah you are right about ensureDeferred. Still not the answer to my question, but thanks

Comment: `DeferredList` provides success or failure because any one of the deferreds in the list can possibly succeed or fail. When dealing with `Deferred` individually, just add an errback to catch instances that fail. Example: `my_query.addErrback(lambda failure: log.error(failure.value))`. If you need the success/fail of a list of `Deferreds` then using `DeferredList` is correct